# Calling external domain web service using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

while i am calling external domain service, I get error like this,
XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Is it possible to load external domain service response? from backbone js. While i am trying to load it load it as a empty response. How to fix this issue?

Comment: What is this external service? Does it support JSONP? Do you control it so you can add CORS headers? Does it already support CORS? Are you getting any error message other than "cannot load"? Are you using Chrome's dev tools to debug?

Comment: this is my service url http://arizonawet.arizona.edu/colorbox/user/23?width=800&height=500. pls update in jsfiddle to call this service. I am very new to this, pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `dataType` to `jsonp` in the `options` hash of (e.g.) your `fetch` call. See for example http://blog.blairvanderhoof.com/post/56277707617/fetching-a-backbone-js-model-or-collection-with-jsonp

Comment: That's good example, but i cant able to get the response as i expected, i.e, for example my service url is http://arizonawet.arizona.edu/colorbox/user/23?width=800&height=500, i cant able to get the result from this one. I am new to backbone so cant able to do this.